# Get pandoc to skip certain sections of document

Tags: latex, pandoc

Ok, so I'm converting Word documents to Latex using Pandoc.

Embedded in my word documents are some latex commands that I've constructed using my reference manager to automatically generate Bibtex citations (i.e. \citep{Author1_Author2_Year}.

This would work perfectly, but I need to get pandoc to skip over these sections of the document as currently it is escaping the characters for latex (i.e. it is converted to \citep{Author1_Author2_Year}.

So, what I want to do is tell pandoc to omit conversion each time it reaches a \citep{*} command. I've read the manual, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of doing this.

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm trying to avoid writing another script to go over the tex document and amend the citations.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html)...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pandoc syntax for citations and run pandoc as follows, it will work:
In your one.docx you write:

```
I want to cite @knuth1984texbook.
```

With

```
pandoc -o two.md one.docx
```

you prepare your markdown-document. Then you create your latex-document:

```
pandoc --biblatex -o three.tex two.md
```

and you get three.tex:

```
I want to cite \textcite{knuth1984texbook}.
```

Preamble and Postamble are missing. So with

```
pandoc --standalone --biblatex -o three.tex two.md
```

you get a complete latex-file, that you can compile with latex.